# Method does not exist error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am working on laravel 5.2.I want to display those members who belongs to that particular group which is open at this time. Actually, i am getting all the members which i have stored in my database but, i only want to access or display only those members who belongs to a particular on which i am currently accessing. I am getting an error: Method groups does not exist. which is shown below:[image][image]

My controller:

```
 public function members($id){
 $dashes=Grouptable::findorFail($id);
 $members=Member::all();
 return view('members' , ['dashes'=>$dashes,'members'=>$members]);

 }

 public function dashboard($id){
 $dashes=Grouptable::findorFail($id);
 return view('dashboard' , ['dashes'=>$dashes]);

 }
 public function addmembers(Request $request){
 $member=new Member();
 $member->members=$request['addmember'];
 $request->groups()->members()->save($member);

 return redirect()->back();
 }
```

My view:

```
  <body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
  <img src="images/ImgResponsive_Placeholder.png" 
  class="img-circle img-  responsive" alt="Placeholder image"> </div>
 <div class="col-lg-7">
 <h1 style="color:black;">{{ $dashes->name }}</h1></div>
    <br />
 </div>
  <div class="row">

 <div class="col-lg-3">

  <button class="btn btn-success"  onclick="myFunction()">
   Add Members +   </button>
   <div>

 <form id="demo" style="display:none;" method="post"
  action="{{ route('addmember') }}">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="addmember">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
 </form>

     </div>
      </div>

    <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-0">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div  id="grp" class="panel-heading">
     <h3 id="grouptitle" class="panel-title">Group Members</h3>
   </div>
     <div  id="zx" class="panel-content">
     <div class="row">
      @foreach($members as $member)
      <section class="col-md-6">

      <div class="row">

      <section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-xs-offset-1
       col-xs-4">
     <img id="imagesize" src="images/g.jpg" class="img-circle"/>
     </section>
     <section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-7 col-xs-7">
      <section class="col-md-12">

       <h5 id="friendname">{{$member->members}}</h5>

       </section>

         </section>
          </div>
          </section>
         </div>

          </section>
          @endforeach

     </div>
      <div id="mn" class="panel-footer"><a id="seemr1"
      href="#.html">See More</a></div>
       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        </body>
```

My routes:

```
         Route::get('/members/{id}',[
         'uses'=>'GroupController@members',
         'as'=>'members'
          ]);
          Route::get('/dashboard/{id}',[
          'uses'=>'GroupController@dashboard',
         'as'=>'dashboard'
           ]);
            Route::post('/memeber/add',[
           'uses'=>'GroupController@addmembers',
           'as'=>'addmember'
           ]);
```

My modals:

```
            Grouptable:
            public function members(){
              return $this->hasMany('App\Member');
             }

           Member:

              public function groups(){
              return $this->hasMany('App\Grouptable');
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are defining the relationship is wrong. I think this is [OneToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship. Like A Group has many users. Then you must define it like this

**MODELS**

```
    Grouptable:
    public function members(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Member','group_id'); // group_id represents the name of the foreign key. It is not neccessary if your foreign key is Grouptable_id, because Laravel automatically guess it unless the foreign key name is explicitly provided 
    }

    Member:
    public function groups(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Grouptable','group_id');
    }
```

To retrieve all members of a particular group say groupid `1`:

```
$members = \App\Gouptable::find(1)->members;
```

**CONTROLLER**
Something seems to be wrong in your `addmembers()` function:

```
public function addmembers(Request $request){
     $member=new Member();
     $member->members=$request['addmember'];
     $request->groups()->members()->save($member); //what is this groups()? 

     //You need to do something like this
     $groupid = $request['groupid']; // send groupid as parameter from form
     Grouptable::find($groupid)->members()->save($member);
     return redirect()->back();
 }
```

Comment: i am getting the same error again after applying your code

Comment: what is the name of the foreign_key in member table? OR share your both table structure

Comment: sorry i don't get  you what are trying to say

Comment: What does your tables looks like? I need to see that

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('groupmembers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
             $table->string('members');
            $table->integer('group_id');

        });
    }

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grouptable1s', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
             $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('user_id');
        });
    }

Comment: actually, i have changed the name of my modals to , grouptable1 and Groupmembers... okkk

Comment: but I don't see any relationship between these two tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120593/discussion-between-vivek-titwal-and-jonju).